# Reference 'PARAM' not supported (reference to group function)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a error in my clause sql

```
SELECT e.id_pedido, 
       d.pregunta, 
       Group_concat(d.respuesta)            AS respuestan, 
       e.cedula_usuario, 
       (SELECT `nombres` 
        FROM   `usuarios` 
        WHERE  `cedula` = e.cedula_usuario) AS nombreUsuario, 
       (SELECT `id_supervisor` 
        FROM   `usuarios` 
        WHERE  `cedula` = e.cedula_usuario) AS idSupervisor, 
       e.cedula_cliente, 
       c.`nit`, 
       c.`contacto`, 
       c.cod_ciudad, 
       c.nom_ciudad, 
       c.cod_barrio, 
       c.n                                  om_barrio, 
       c.direccion, 
       c.telefono, 
       e.fecha_pedido, 
       e.hora_final, 
       (SELECT p.descripcion 
        FROM   `preguntas_encuesta_obligatoria` AS p 
        WHERE  p.encuesta = '34' 
               AND p.id_preg = d.pregunta 
               AND p.consecutivo_preg = '1' 
               AND p.tipo = '1')            AS preguntaFin, 
       (SELECT Group_concat(descripcion) AS descripcion 
        FROM   `preguntas_encuesta_obligatoria` 
        WHERE  encuesta = '34' 
               AND id_preg = d.pregunta 
               AND consecutivo_preg IN ( respuestan ) 
               AND tipo = '2')              AS respuestaFin, 
       (SELECT `unidad_de_negocio` 
        FROM   `usuarios` 
        WHERE  `cedula` = e.cedula_usuario) AS unidad_negocio, 
       (SELECT `id_unidad_negocio` 
        FROM   `usuarios` 
        WHERE  `cedula` = e.cedula_usuario) AS id_unidad_negocio 
FROM   `encuesta_obligatoria` AS e 
       INNER JOIN encuesta_obligatoria_detalle AS d 
               ON e.id_pedido = d.id_encuesta 
       INNER JOIN clientes AS c 
               ON e.cedula_cliente = c.cedula 
WHERE  e.`fecha_pedido` >= '2017-02-13' 
       AND e.`fecha_pedido` <= '2017-02-16' 
       AND d.encuesta = '34' 
GROUP  BY e.id_pedido, 
          d.pregunta 
ORDER  BY e.id_pedido DESC, 
          d.pregunta ASC, 
          d.respuesta ASC
```

Reference 'respuestan' not supported (reference to group function)

Comment: You might consider formatting the query so others could read it.

Comment: try http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm tool to format your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)** Return a concatenated string, and you are trying to use it as a collection.

```
SELECT e.id_pedido, 
   d.pregunta, 
   Group_concat(d.respuesta)         AS respuestan, 
   (SELECT Group_concat(descripcion) AS descripcion 
    FROM   `preguntas_encuesta_obligatoria` 
    WHERE  encuesta = '34' 
           AND id_preg = d.pregunta 
           AND consecutivo_preg IN ( respuestan )  <-- You cant do this
           AND tipo = '2')              AS respuestaFin,
```

Instead you have to include a proper `SELECT`

```
consecutivo_preg IN  ( SELECT consecutivo_preg FROM ... WHERE ...)
```